# Consultar la mejor coincidencia Linq Contains .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

tengo la siguiente consulta en Linq

```
PerfilMedico entidad = (from x in esquema.PerfilMedico
                                    where x.Estado!=(int)Estado.Eliminado && x.Nombre.Contains(NAVA) && (x.CiudadId == ciudadId)
                                    select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

el problema que tengo es que en mi base de datos existen muchos perfiles médicos con nombres parecidos por ejemplo NAVA y NAVARRO lo que hace que la consulta me devuelva el primer perfil medico que contenga NAVA que en este caso seria NAVARRO

mi pregunta es si puedo hacer que en lugar que me devuelva el primer resultado encontrado me devuelva la mejor coincidencia ejemplo si yo busco NAVA me devuelva NAVA y no NAVARRO ya que NAVARRO esta registrado antes que NAVA

Comment: porque no usar `Equals("NAVA")` en vez de `Contains("NAVA")` ?

Comment: Hazle un orderby

Comment: @L.Ronquillo  por que no siempre el nombre a buscar será el mismo que en la Base de datos, la búsqueda no siempre será nava sino una cadena cualquiera ingresada por el usuario

Comment: @Japv podrías explicarme un poco mas sobre como me podría ayudar un orderby

Comment: Puede ser por ejemplo naba y en la bd sea Navarro, tu lo que quieres es la mayor coincidencia posible?, si pones naba, por ejemplo te devolvería como coincidencia nava, Navarro, nhavarro